# Implementation of increment in question number

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make every question number start from 1. Currently, the question numbers are based on their respective number in the database. How can I make it to start from 1?

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h1> Quiz</h1>


         <?php echo form_open('user/resultdisplay/', ['class' =>'form-horizontal']);?>


        <?php if(count($questions) > 0):?>
            <?php foreach($questions as $row):?>

            <p><?=$row->ch_id?>. <b><?=$row->ques?></b></p>

            <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des1?>"> <?=$row->ch_des1?><br>
            <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des2?>"> <?=$row->ch_des2?><br>
            <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des3?>"> <?=$row->ch_des3?><br>
            <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des4?>"> <?=$row->ch_des4?><br> 

            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php else:?>
                <tr>
                    <td>No records found!</td>
                </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
    </body>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit!">

        </form>

    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Add a counter and increase it.

Comment: Use an [ordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

Comment: Why do you keep going in and out of PHP for every line? There are several blocks there that could just be *one* PHP block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter and increase it manually:

```
<?php if(count($questions) > 0):?>
    <?php $index = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($questions as $row):?>

    <p><?=$index++?>. <b><?=$row->ques?></b></p>

    <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des1?>"> <?=$row->ch_des1?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des2?>"> <?=$row->ch_des2?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des3?>"> <?=$row->ch_des3?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des4?>"> <?=$row->ch_des4?><br> 

    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php else:?>
        <tr>
            <td>No records found!</td>
        </tr>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I have tried something similar like that. I got the first one correct but got this <?=$index++?> wrong. Thank you, its working perfectly. Will accept the answer in 10 mins.